# Getting an exception while using HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

Tags: android, exception, httpresponse

I'm trying to request the response from server, but when I use "HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);", program enters the exception case.

Here is my code:

function for getting response from server

public String executeHttpGet(String username, String password) throws Exception {

```
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI("http://emapzoom.com/setting/device_login"+ "?device_id=" +password+ "&login_name="+ username));



        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();
        String page = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(page);
        return page;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

code used in activity

```
     try{

            test=executeHttpGet(name,pass);

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
```

when I execute, program enter the catch block!

please help me !!!
thx in advance!

Comment: Please log the exception (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) and add the entire stacktrace to your question.  That said, it's may just be missing the INTERNET permission (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET).

Answer (score 2):

If you're building against any version of Android >= Honeycomb you cannot make network calls on the main thread.  Try putting this in an Async Task and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of dell116 are right.

I had the same problem on ICS and solve it asynchronously with this code:

```
private void getResponseThread(final String url) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String cadHTTP = getResponse(url);
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.obj = cadHTTP;
            handlerHTTP.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }).start();
}

private String getResponse(String url) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet del = new HttpGet(url);
    del.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

    String respStr;
    try {
        HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(del);
        respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        Log.e("RestService","Error!", ex);
        respStr = "";
    }

    Log.e("getResponse",respStr);
    return respStr;
}

private Handler handlerHTTP = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String res = (String) msg.obj;
        //CONTINUE HERE
        nexTask(res);
    }
};
```

Regards! :)