# exception while using HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

Tags: android, exception, httpresponse, android-debug

I am trying to do the same as this guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696718/getting-an-exception-while-using-httpresponse-response-client-executerequest) and I am using AsyncTask to call the executeHttpPost. However, by debugging the application, when it reaches the line

`HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);`

it skip everything to the line

`if (in != null) {`

I am pretty sure that the URL is working.

```
public static String executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
        request.setEntity(formEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();
        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}}}
            public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {
                BufferedReader in = null;
                try {
                    HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                    request.setURI(new URI(url));
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                    StringBuffer sb     = new StringBuffer("");
                    String line = "";
                    String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + NL);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    String result = sb.toString();
                    return result;
                } finally {
                    if (in != null) {
                        try {   
                            in.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }}}}}
```

logcat:

```
W/ActivityThread﹕ Application is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
I/art﹕ Debugger is active
Debugger has connected
I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1496)
I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/24/14, 167c270, I68fa98814b
I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 429 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 703 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 3307 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Show us your code and stacktrace

Comment: Please indent the code properly and add the printstacktrace

Comment: @avk thanks for guiding, I am new here :) please check the updates.

Comment: First start removing in.close() in your try-block, because after try you will always enter the finally-block anyway.. What happens is you try to close the same file twice. This fails.

Comment: This is a template which worked for many many times, I am pretty sure there is nothing to change in that code.

Comment: You say that each time you debug you end up in the catch clause. When you do, prinstacktrace contains the info I requested you to post. So please do that first.

Comment: I am sorry I am not making myself clear, can you check the update?

Comment: Skips... Then also add a catch clause in the first try block and printstacktrace from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, I added the permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

to AndroidManifest.xml